# How to create an Ajax Cascading/Chained/Dependant Dropdown list or Select Box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am very new to JavaScript I have somewhat of a basic understanding but my skills are limited.

I need to create a 4 tier drop down list with each tier is dependant on the previous entry.

it will be a Car Make >>> Car Model >>>> Engine Size >>> Varient

I found a jquery tutorial when all the data is loaded together however eventually the fields will have over 1000 different car variants in total so this will put affect the load time of each page.

Whilst googling through the internet for solutions I read up on AJAX which sounds like an ideal solution to my problem but most tutorials I have found of AJAX and drop down lists are to do with ASP.NET databases. I don't need to link it to a database i just need the dependant select box function

An example of what i want is [Superchips Website](http://superchips.co.uk/) the tool on the left hand side under the title "How will my vehicle improve?" I wish to recreate something similar to that.

Any help or tutorials people might have will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: AJAX requests are used to load data asynchronously from a web server, so you don't have to constantly submit a form or navigate to another URL. What happens on the web server is independent of the AJAX call, provided what is returned is in the correct format and can be handled with your JavaScript code. However, your web server will need to get the data to return from somewhere, and that sounds like it *would* be a database.

Comment: So you are suggesting I build a database to store all the information on?

Comment: That depends, where is the information currently coming from?

Comment: I should clarify I am making a website using wordpress and the information will be stored on wordpress posts

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a JSON file if you don't have access to a database server. 
http://www.secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp

I recommend you to use jQuery for that requirement. You can use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function or the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) function if you use a JSON file.

Here is an example I coded a few weeks ago:

```
var strHtmlOutput = "";

$.getJSON('cities.json', function(data) {

        // Loop over all records in the json file
        $.each(data.cities, function() {        
            var strName = $(this).attr("name");
            var strCityId = $(this).attr("id");
            var strProvinceId = $(this).attr("provinceid");

                                strHtmlOutput += "<option value='" + strCityId + "'>";
            strHtmlOutput += strName;
            strHtmlOutput += "</option>";

        });     
    });

// Appending new records in the City dropdown list
$("#strCityId").append((strHtmlOutput);
```

JSON file content:

```
{
    "cities": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "provinceid": "1",
        "name": "Montreal"
    },

    {
        "id": "2",
        "provinceid": "1",
        "name": "Quebec"
    },

    {
        "id": "3",
        "provinceid": "2",
        "name": "Ottawa"
    },

    {
        "id": "4",
        "provinceid": "2",
        "name": "Mississauga"
    },

    {
        "id": "5",
        "provinceid": "3",
        "name": "Vancouver"
    },

    {
        "id": "6",
        "provinceid": "3",
        "name": "Victoria"
    }

    ]
}
```

Hope this helps!